# Extract text from Entry Box ktinker Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, data-extraction, tkinter-button

I have a tkinter project and need the text, I put it in the Entry box, printed it in the console. but when I use get() I get empty space in the console.

[image]

this is my interface. when I put 1234 I could place it above when I click the button "Pull record data" but I need that number in my console. to use that entry for other things. but when I try to print it I get nothing in the console like this:

[image]
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("390x500")
root.title("Airtable Project Tracker")

```
str = tk.StringVar(root)
str.set('ie. recveGd8w9ukxLkk9')

tk.Label(root, textvariable=str).pack()

recid = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
recid.pack(pady = 10)
print(recid.get())

id_button = tk.Button(root, text="Pull record data", width=50, command = lambda:str.set(recid.get()))
id_button.pack(pady = 5)
```

Comment: You need to wait to call `get()` until the user has entered some data. You're calling it in the print statement about a microsecond after creating the entry.

Comment: interesting. but how can I wait?

Comment: create a function, then call the function from a button or from a binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already implemented it above, you can get the input plane value using `get()` (`recide.get()`). Another method is to use the parameter `textvariable` as shown below. Where the value can be accessed again using `get()` (`text.get()`).

```py
text = tk.StringVar()
recide = tk.Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=text)
```

In my test case I could not reproduce this error. I modified their code slightly to output the value in the console as shown below.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    str.set(recid.get())
    print(recid.get())

root = tk.Tk()

str = tk.StringVar(root)
str.set('ie. recveGd8w9ukxLkk9')

tk.Label(root, textvariable=str).pack()

recid = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
recid.pack(pady = 10)
print(recid.get())

id_button = tk.Button(root, text="Pull record data", width=50, command = test)
id_button.pack(pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting the same result. the code works but nothing in the console

Comment: I do not suspect the problem in the code you showed. How do you access this value and output it in the console? (Can you share the code section?)